# InstallScript String replace fails in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installscript, installshield-2009

I am now facing a problem with the installer that i have created with InstallSheild 2009.

There are some configuration files which need the installation path of the application.

and this is done by the installer through an installscript.

On building the installer we uses a template '`<Base Path>`' and at the end of installation the install script replaces the string with the install location. (say C:\Program files\)

This is made for windows servers. and it is working fine in windows server 2003.

And it works in Windows server 2008 if the User is ADMINISTRATOR.

Other wise it fails to replace the strings even thought the installed user has full previlege.

Anyone having any idea regarding this please help me....

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved when I just right click and selected 'Run as Administrator'